# Proof that there is an $x \in R^+$ such that $\sqrt{x}+\ln(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, roots

So I was trying to solve this problem and I wasn't able to complete the proof . To translate the problem, let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}+\ln(x)$. Using the Intermediate Value Theorem , if we assume there is a $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$ we want to show there exist $a,b \in R^+$ with $b>a$ such that:
$$f(a)<0<f(b) $$
Plugging in  $f(x) = \sqrt{x}+\ln(x)$:
$$\sqrt{b}+\ln(b)>0>\sqrt{a}+\ln(a)$$
By comparing each inequality, we need to have:
$$\ln(b)>-\sqrt{b}$$
$$-\ln(a)>\sqrt{a}$$
$$\sqrt{b}+\ln(b)> \sqrt{a}+\ln(a)$$
And I don't know how to proceed from here (I don't even know if I should be using the IVT).

Comment: If $a$ is near zero, then $\sqrt{a}$ is near zero but $\ln a$ is very negative. Does that help?

Comment: You could try directly taking $a = 1/e$, and using some bounds on $e$. (for instance, $e > 1$).

Comment: You have to **find** the $a$ and $b$. Try some numbers. Play around with it.

Comment: Either you can give an exact solution (which seems impossible to me) or you have to use the continuity of $f$ and  the IVT.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} (\sqrt{x}+\ln x)= -\infty$. Hence there must be some $a>0$ such that $\sqrt{a}+\ln(a)<0$. Also, if we let $b=1$ then $\sqrt{b}+\ln(b)=1>0$. Hence by IVT there is some $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\sqrt{c}+\ln(c)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing here is that the question is given to be solved in a general way (or at least I interpret it as so) and thus I don't think that taking values of the functions is "allowed" in the proof that is asked.

Comment: @NicolásMaílloGómez: Of course it is allowed. You need to think about this a little!

Comment: @TonyK Ok, let me be honest here. The question was from a 4-question test for a college exam, so that is essentially why I tackled it in a general way. So, apart from your answer which was already useful, is there any way to continue with the proof I was doing above?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that there exist $a,b \in R^+$ with $b>a$ such that
$$\sqrt{b}+\ln(b)>0>\sqrt{a}+\ln(a) .$$
Take $b = 1$. Then $\sqrt{b}+\ln(b) = 1$. Take $a = e^{-2}$. Since $e > 1$, we have $a < 1^{-2} =1 = b$. Moreover, $\sqrt{a}+\ln(a) = e^{-1} - 2 < 1^{-1} - 2 = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you look for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=\sqrt x+\log(x)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\qquad >0 \quad \forall x >0$$

When $x\to 0$, $f(x) \to -\infty$ and $f(1)=1$; so the root is is $(0,1)$.

You could even bracket more since $f\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)<0$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) >0$,so the root is is $(\frac 1e,\frac 12)$.